# Getting type of object assigned to field

Tags: java, reflection

I am inspecting "ReflectMe" class via reflection.
Using getDeclaredFields method I got the "str" field.

Now I need to get the class "Target" which static method is assigned to that field.

Is it possible?

Code:

```
package myproj.reflect;
public class Target {
    public static final String theString = "abcd";
}

package myproj.reflect;
public class ReflectMe {
    private String str = Target.theString;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();                      
     String theclass = "myproj.reflect.ReflectMe";                   
    Class myClass = loader.loadClass(theclass);
    Field[] fields = myClass.getDeclaredFields();
}
```

}

In other words, I need to get the "Target" class.

Comment: Use `Class.forName()` instead of the first three lines of your `main`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to get the `Target` class from the class definition of `ReflectMe` via. the field, I don't think you can do that through the reflection API; you can get the class definition and the values of instance variables, but you cannot introspect the expressions themselves.

Comment: so there is no way to get it?

Comment: Absolutely not.  The only alternative would be to inspect the source code itself.

Comment: @JustinKSU, well I have just the .class file not the .java source

Comment: Short of decompiling it, I don't think you have a way to determine this programmatically.

Comment: There is a tool call JAD.  I don't know if it has an API.  Good luck.

Comment: unfortunately no API so it can't be used.